# How to fix a : TypeError 'tuple' object does not support item assignment

Tags: python, pygame

The following fragment of code from this tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/24252/beginning-game-programming-for-teens-with-python

```
for badguy in badguys:
        if badguy[0]<-64:
            badguys.pop(index)
        badguy[0]-=7
        index+=1
    for badguy in badguys:
        screen.blit(badguyimg, badguy)
```

is giving me a :

> TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment

I understand that this could be becuse `badguy` is a tuple. This means it is immutable(you can not change its values)  Ive tried the following:

```
t= list(badguy)
        t[0]= t[0]-7
        i+=1
```

I converted the tuple to a list so we can minus 7. But in the game nothing happens.

Does any one know what I could do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Change this

```
badguy[0]-=7
```

into this

```
badguy = list(badguy)
badguy[0]-=7
badguy = tuple(badguy)
```

Alternatively, if you can leave `badguy` as a `list`, then don't even use tuples and you'll be fine with your current code (with the added change of using lists instead of tuples)

Comment: Im getting no movement in my game, with those changes

Comment: @Pro-grammer: Then, you have other issues. The solution I proposed takes care of your `tuple` issue. If you have a different problem, I suggest making another post

Comment: It may not have helped much for you but was great for me! OSGeo GDAL GetGeoTransform returns a tuple which I needed to adjust by x -= 0.1, y += 0.1 and then convert back into tuple for SetGeoTransform. Just what I needed - a tuple at both ends and editable inbetween!

Answer (score 4):

Another solution is instead of

```
badguy[0] -= 7
```

to do

```
badguy = (badguy[0] - 7,) + badguy[1:]
```

This creates a new tuple altogether with the updated value in the zeroth element.

Answer (score -1):

You can do a np.copy() and work with her.

```py
badguy_copy = np.copy(badguy)
```