# How to fill a tuple with a for loop

Tags: python, python-collections

I am trying to fill a tuple with named tuples using a for loop.

The example code below works:

```
import collections

Experiment = collections.namedtuple('Experiment', ['parameter', ])

nsize = 3

parameters = {}
for n in range(0, nsize):
    parameters[n] = n +1
   

experiments = (
        Experiment(parameter = parameters[0]),   
        Experiment(parameter = parameters[1]),
        Experiment(parameter = parameters[2]),)
```

However, I would like to replace the last section with a for loop:

```
for n in range(0, nsize):
    experiments[n] = Experiment(parameter = parameters[n])
```

Which gives the error:

```
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Aren't tuples immutable? In that case, it makes sense that you can't change it.

Comment: If the indices of `parameters` really is just a set of continuous integers from 0 to `nsize - 1`, consider using a list instead. `parameters = list(range(1,nsize+1))`. Then Mark Meyer's answer becomes simply `tuple(Experiment(x) for x in parameters)`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix a : TypeError 'tuple' object does not support item assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19338209/how-to-fix-a-typeerror-tuple-object-does-not-support-item-assignment)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Tuples](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) are immutable, so you can't modify them after creating them. If you need to modify the data structure, you'll need to use a list.

However, instead of using a `for` loop, you can pass a generator expression to `tuple()` and make the tuple all at once. This will give you both the tuple you want and a way to make it cleanly.

```
import collections

Experiment = collections.namedtuple('Experiment', ['parameter', ])

nsize = 3

parameters = {}
for n in range(0, nsize):
    parameters[n] = n + 1
    
expirements = tuple(Experiment(parameter = parameters[n]) for n in range(nsize))
# (Experiment(parameter=1), Experiment(parameter=2), Experiment(parameter=3))
```

Comment: This works great, thanks for the super quick reply!

Answer (score 0):

Tuple are immutable, you should consider changing it to a list.

Answer (score 0):

Since tuples are immutable, you can convert tuples to something mutable, do you stuff and then convert it back to tuples using tuple () function